# inputStream and utf 8 sometimes shows "?" characters

Tags: java, utf-8

So I've been dealing with this problem for over a months now and I also checked almost every possible related solution over here in and over google but I couldn't find anything that really solved my case.
my problem is that i'm trying to download an html source from a website but what i'm getting in most cases is that some of the text shows some "?" characters in it,most likely beacuse the site is in Hebrew.
Here's my code,

```java
    public static InputStream openHttpGetConnection(String url)
            throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        return inputStream;

    }
    public static String downloadSource(String url) {
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = openHttpGetConnection(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        int bytesRead;
        String str = "";
        byte[] inpputBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(inpputBuffer)) > 0) {
                String read = new String(inpputBuffer, 0, bytesRead,"UTF-8");
                str +=read;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return str;

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know for sure you have to use UTF8 ? Why not trust the HTTP response's Content-Type header and/or the response body `<meta` charset if it's HTML ?
Plus : your Stirng concatenation may be broken, one can not concatenate UTF Strings from bytes at arbitrary boundaries.

Comment: It's a very good point by @GPI about the boundaries. Imagine if after filling the input buffer the last byte read is only the first byte of a two-byte UTF8 character? When you build the String from that buffer for sure you will finish with an invalid character.

Comment: @GPI I did so,and yet I was still getting some "?" in my text,so I assumed it may be something to do with the encdoing such as UTF-8.
Is there any better way to create a String from a bytes then?

Comment: @jas that might be true and this could be the cause for getting some invalid character,there is any way of doing it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read characters from a byte stream with a given encoding, use a `Reader`. In your case it would be something like:

```
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inpputStream, "UTF-8");
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((charsRead = isr.read(inputBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        String read = new String(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead);
        str += read;
    }
```

You can see that the bytes will be read in directly as characters --- it's the reader's problem to know if it needs to read one or two bytes, e.g., to create the character in the buffer. It's basically your approach but decoding as the bytes are being read in, instead of after.

Comment: Wow,you are best man,now it's working like charm.
I really appreciate that,been trying to solve this for a long time now.
Thank you very much,I cant upvote you since my rep is low,but I would have done so if I could.

Comment: Fantastic, @DorB, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Converting an `InputStream` to a String entails specifying an encoding, just as you do at `new String(inpputBuffer, 0, bytesRead,"UTF-8");`.

But your approach as several drawbacks.

### How do you know you have to use UTF8 ?

When retreiving HTTP content, generally speaking, you can not know in advance what encoding will be used in the HTTP response. But HTTP provides a mechanism for specifying that, using the Content-Type header.

More specifically, your response object should have a `Content-Type` "header", that has an "attribute" called `encoding`. In the response, it should look something like :

```
Content-Type: text/html; encoding=UTF-8
```

You should use whatever is after the `encoding=` part to transform your `byte`s to `char`s.
Seeing you seem to use Apache HTTPClient, their documentation states :

> You can set the content type header for a request with the addRequestHeader method in each method and **retrieve the encoding for the response body with the getResponseCharSet method.
>
>   If the response is known to be a String, you can use the getResponseBodyAsString method which will automatically use the encoding specified in the Content-Type header or ISO-8859-1 if no charset is specified.**.

*Alternate way*

If there is no Content-Type header, and if you *know* your content is HTML, then you can try to convert it as a String using some encoding (UTF or ISO Latin preferably), and try to find some content matching `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, and use that as the charset. This should only be a fail-over.

### Any byte sequence is not convertible to a String

Drawback number two is that you read any number of bytes from your stream, and try to convert it to a String, which may not be possible.

In practice, UTF-8 can encode some "characters" across several bytes. For example "é" can be encoded as `0xC3A9`. So say for example that the response consists of two "é" characters. If your first call to `read` returns :

```
[c3, a9, c3]
```

Your conversion to a String using new `String(byte[], off, enc)` will leave the last byte apart, because it does not match a valid UTF8 sequence.

Your following read will get what's left to read

```
[a9]
```

Which is (whatever that is) not a "é" character.

Bottom line : you can not convert even a valid UTF-8 sequence to byte using your pattern.

Going forward : you use HTTPClient, use their method of HTTP Response to String conversion.
If you wish to do it yourself, the easy way is to copy your input to a byte array, and then convert the byte array. Something along the lines of (pseudo code) :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream responseContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
copyAllBytes(responseInputStream, responseContent)
byte[] rawResponse = responseContent.toByteArray();
String stringResponse = new String(rawResponse, encoding);
```

But you could also use a `CharsetDecoder` if you want a fully streamed implementation (one that does not buffer the response fully into memory), or as @jas answers, wrap your inputStream to a reader and concatenate the output (preferably into a StringBuilder, which should be faster if a high number of concatenation is to occur).

Comment: Thanks you man,I used what @jas said and I managed to slove my case,I really appreciate your comment since it halped unserdatnd my problem more further.
I can't upvote you but you more than deserve it , thank you.

Comment: @jas answer is a good one. Mine just doesn't assume the server uses UTF-8).

So when your code breaks at some point in the future (which it will, at some point, that's guaranteed, maybe 3 years from now, maybe when you'll use it in another context, but eventually it will). Then you'll know where to look ;)